# Abline command is not showing a regression line?

Tags: r, linear-regression, abline

I'm new to R programming and I'm trying to plot a regression line for this data set, but it doesn't seem to be working.
I followed exactly what my professor was using, however it doesn't seem to be working. I've also interchanged the abline command with `abline(lm(batters$EMH~batters$TB))` with similar results.

Here is my code for it:

```
batters<-read.table(header=TRUE, text="
X   AVG EBH  TB   OPS K.to.BB.Ratio
1     LeMahieu 0.327  61 312 0.893          1.95
2      Urshela 0.314  55 236 0.889          3.48
3       Torres 0.278  64 292 0.871          2.64
4        Judge 0.272  46 204 0.921          2.21
5      Sanchez 0.232  47 208 0.841          3.13
6         Wong 0.285  40 202 0.784          1.76
7       Molina 0.270  34 167 0.711          2.52
8  Goldschmidt 0.260  60 284 0.821          2.13
9        Ozuna 0.243  53 230 0.804          1.84
10      DeJong 0.233  62 259 0.762          2.39
11      Altuve 0.298  61 275 0.903          1.98
12     Bregman 0.296  80 328 1.015          0.69
13    Springer 0.292  62 283 0.974          1.69
14     Reddick 0.275  36 205 0.728          1.83
15    Chirinos 0.238  40 162 0.791          2.45
16   Bellinger 0.305  84 351 1.035          1.14
17      Turner 0.290  51 244 0.881          1.72
18      Seager 0.272  64 236 0.817          2.23
19      Taylor 0.262  45 169 0.794          3.11
20       Muncy 0.251  58 251 0.889          1.65
21     Meadows 0.291  69 296 0.922          2.43
22      Garcia 0.282  47 227 0.796          4.03
23        Pham 0.273  56 255 0.818          1.52
24        Choi 0.261  41 188 0.822          1.69
25      Adames 0.254  46 222 0.735          3.32
26      Yelich 0.329  76 328 1.101          1.48
27       Braun 0.285  55 232 0.849          3.09
28   Moustakas 0.254  66 270 0.845          1.85
29     Grandal 0.246  56 240 0.848          1.28
30       Arcia 0.223  32 173 0.633          2.53")

plot(batters$EBH,batters$TB,main="Attribute Pairing 5",xlab="EBH",ylab="TB")
lm(formula = batters$EBH~batters$TB)
#Call:
#lm(formula = batters$EBH ~ batters$TB)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)   batters$TB  
#    -4.1275       0.2416  

lin_model_1<-lm(formula = batters$EBH~batters$TB)
summary(lin_model_1)

abline(-4.12752, 0.24162)
```

I apologize for the messy coding, this is for a class.

Comment: You plotted EBH as x and TB as y, but then you reversed their roles in the regression. Should have been `lm(formula = TB  ~ EBH, data=batters)`. If you had used a formula argument in both plot and lm it would have been easier to keep their roles straight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula is backwards in the `lm()` function call.  The dependent variable is on the left side of the "~".
In your plot the y-axis (dependent variable) is TB, but in the linear regression model, it is defined as the independent variable.  So for the linear regression model to work, one needs to swap EBH & TB.

```
plot(batters$EBH,batters$TB,main="Attribute Pairing 5",xlab="EBH",ylab="TB")
model <-lm(formula = batters$TB ~batters$EBH)

model
```

> Call: lm(formula = batters$TB ~ batters$EBH)
>
> Coefficients: (Intercept)  batters$EBH
> 46.510        3.603

```
 abline(model)
 #or
 abline (46.51, 3.60)
```

Also if you pass the "model" to `abline` you can avoid the need to specify the slope and intercept with `abline`